# function returning the same value for every row

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Below is the function that I am using with the sample data. I am wanting to have the result be like below. However, all i am getting is the word, "board" in the output. Any suggesting on how to  make this operate correctly.

```
 row 1 : The state board of Accounting
 row 2 : The state board of Economists

 rearrange_name <- function(name) {

 # Split the input name string based on commas
 split_name <- strsplit(name, split = ",")[[1]]

 # If there's more than one comma-separated value in the split name
 if (length(split_name) > 1) {

# Extract the last part after the split (typically a descriptor like "The Board of...")
prefix <- trimws(split_name[length(split_name)])

# Combine the other parts (excluding the last) back together using commas
rest <- trimws(paste(split_name[-length(split_name)], collapse = ","))

# Create the rearranged name by placing the descriptor at the start
new_name <- paste(prefix, rest)
} else {
# If there's no comma in the name, return it as is
new_name <- split_name[1]
}

 # Return the rearranged name
 return(new_name)
 }


  board <- c("Accounting, The State Board of", "Economists, The state Board of", "Medical Examiners, The State Board of ")

  license <- data.frame(board)
 
 license <- license %>% mutate("board" = rearrange_name("board"))
```

Sample data below

board <- c(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your function is it's not vectorized. If you put multiple values in, you only get one value out. A vectorized version of your function would look like this

```
rearrange_name <- function(name) {
  # Split the input name string based on commas
  sapply(strsplit(name, split = ","), function(split_name) {
    # If there's more than one comma-separated value in the split name
    if (length(split_name) > 1) {
      
      # Extract the last part after the split (typically a descriptor like "The Board of...")
      prefix <- trimws(split_name[length(split_name)])
      
      # Combine the other parts (excluding the last) back together using commas
      rest <- trimws(paste(split_name[-length(split_name)], collapse = ","))
      
      # Create the rearranged name by placing the descriptor at the start
      paste(prefix, rest)
    } else {
      # If there's no comma in the name, return it as is
      split_name[1]
    }
  })
}
```

We use `sapply` to apply the transformation to each row of the column. Then you want to use

```
license %>% mutate(board = rearrange_name(board))
```

so you aren't translating the literal string "board"

Answer (score 4):

Your function is over complex and could be replaced by a short `gsub`:

```r
license %>%
  mutate(board = gsub("^(.+), (.+)$", "\\2 \\1", trimws(board)))
#>                                  board
#> 1        The State Board of Accounting
#> 2        The state Board of Economists
#> 3 The State Board of Medical Examiners
```

---

**Explanation**

`gsub` matches text using regular expressions and replaces the matched text with a string of your choosing.

In this case, the regular expression is

- `^(.+)` : match and *capture* all characters until the next specified match
- `,`  : match (but don't capture) the string `,`
- `(.+)$` : match and capture all remaining characters in the string

The replacement string `"\\2 \\1"` means "replace all the matched characters (in this case, the whole string) with the second capture group, then a space, then the first capture group".

In other words, the call to `gsub` simply swaps the two halves of the string on either side of the `,`  and replaces the `,`  with a single space.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this answer, please? I see it uses regex that I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

Add `dplyr::rowwise()` to mimic a for-loop. The current method is just using the first row of `board`.

```
license <- license %>% rowwise() %>%
mutate(new_board=rearrange_name(board))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

First, the function returns "board" because you didn't apply the function to the column named `board`, but to the `"board"` string. Change `"board"` into `board` to apply the function correctly to the column.

After that correction, the second issue with your function is that you are applying it to the whole column, but it seems that you want to apply it to each row individually. Therefore, if you use `group_by(board)` (or group by another variable that uniquely identifies each observation), and then use `mutate(board2 = rearrange_name(board))`, you'll achieve the expected result of applying the function to each string individually.